# Excel VBA copy cells from sheet1 and insert them in header sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy

I want to copy from sheet1 some cells and insert them between header of sheet2. I wrote the code below and a button to execute it but the problem is that everytime i click on the button, it inserts new header. How can i change it?

```
lastColumnS1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, lastColumnS1)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
lastColumn3 = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Range("B1").Select    
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight  
Range(Cells(2, lastColumn3), Cells(3, lastColumn3)).Select
Selection.Cut
lastColumn3_ = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Range(Cells(2, lastColumn3_), Cells(3, lastColumn3_)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Sample data

```
Sheet1:

ID   Name   x    y    z 
1    AA 
2    BB

Sheet2:

ID  Name
3   KK 
6   LL

desired result of Sheet2:

ID   x    y    z    Name
3                    KK
6                    LL
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're using to get the last used column does not always work. In fact it seems to increment each time it is used. The following will retrieve the last column properly:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```